# C# AmbiguousMatchException when GetProperty and trying to map two objects with eachother

Tags: c#, propertyinfo

I'm trying to make a function that maps a eUsers list object to a user list object. It will actually map a few properties, but when `propertyInfo.Name == "UserName"`, it'll throw me a `AmbiguousMatchException` on the following line:

```
typeof(User)
    .GetProperty(ePropertyInfo.Name, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetField)
    .SetValue(user, ePropertyInfo.GetValue(currentEUser));
```

I tested and it seems it being triggered by the GetProperty method. I'm not really sure what could cause this. Here is the full function:

```
private List<User> ConvertEUsersToUsers(List<eUser> eUsers)
{
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    User user = null;

    IList<PropertyInfo> eUserProps = new List<PropertyInfo>(eUsers.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperties());
    IList<PropertyInfo> userProps = typeof(User).GetProperties();
    foreach (eUser currentEUser in eUsers)
    {
        user = new User();
        foreach (PropertyInfo ePropertyInfo in eUserProps)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in userProps)
            {
                if (propertyInfo.Name == ePropertyInfo.Name)
                {
                    if (ePropertyInfo.CanWrite)
                    {
                        typeof(User)
                            .GetProperty(ePropertyInfo.Name, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetField)
                            .SetValue(user, ePropertyInfo.GetValue(currentEUser));
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        users.Add(user);
    }
    return users;
}
```

EDIT:

Here is a part of the User and eUser class:

```
[Serializable]
[Application(7)]
[Table("Users")]
public partial class User : MembershipUser, IPrincipal, IIdentity, IEntity, IIdNameClass {

    [Column("Name")]
    public new EntityField UserName { get; set; }
}

[Table("Users")]
public class eUser : User
{
    [NotMapped]
    public Boolean selected { get; set; }

    public new UserTypes UserType { get; set; }

    public eUser() : base()
    {
        selected = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `User` class?

Comment: Have you tried removing this BindingFlags.IgnoreCase?

Comment: @stuartd added the classes

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to do this conversion and not just cast them to their base class, e.g. `eUsers.Cast<User>()`?

Comment: It is documented https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zy0d4103(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are shadowing a property called `UserName` in one of your base classes by using the `new` keyword when declaring `UserName` on your `User` class. This means that there is in fact more than one property called `UserName`: the original one from one of the base classes, and the new one in `User`. This is what causes the `AmbiguousMatchException`.

Try using the `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` flag to only fetch properties declared on the type in question: `User`.